# POST Request Upload image to amazon s3 using lambda python and api gateway gives error: could not parse request body into JSON

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to create an api using lambda (python 3.9) & API Gateway, I am accepting binary file but when testing in postmanAPI it gives and error as follows:

Postman Error:

```
{"message": "Could not parse request body into json: Could not parse payload into json: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0xbf\n at [Source: (byte[])\"\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\u0000\u0010JFIF\u0000\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0000`\u0000`\u0000\u0000\uFFFD\uFFFD0\uFFFDExif\u0000\u0000MM\u0000*\u0000\u0000\u0000\b\u0000\u0004\u00011\u0000\u0002\u0000\u0000\u0000\u000B\u0000\u0000\u0010J\uFFFDi\u0000\u0004\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0010V\uFFFD%\u0000\u0004\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0000 \uFFFD\uFFFD\u001C\u0000\u0007\u0000\u0000\u0010\f\u0000\u0000\u0000>\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u001C\uFFFD\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0010\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\"[truncated 330450 bytes]; line: 1, column: 3]"}
```

Lambda Function:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
bucket = 'non-image-bucket'

# Get the image data from the request body
image_data = event['body']

# Generate a unique filename for the image
filename = 'image.jpg'

# Upload the image to the S3 bucket
s3.put_object(Body=image_data, Bucket=bucket, Key=filename)

print('Image uploaded to S3')

return {
    'statusCode': 200,
    'body': 'Image uploaded successfully'
}
```

Postman Config While Testing API is as follows:

[image: postman header]

[image: postman config main]

I need help solving this issue.

I have tried changing my content-headers as application/json , image/jpeg. but it's still not working. and i don't know why it is passing data as json when i am accepting binary code

Comment: how did you configure API Gateway? By default, in API Gateway you will have application/json as content type.